# Unboxing and inspecting a trait object

Tags: rust

Here's a simple application that duplicates 2 times on stdout the contents of stdin:

```
use std::{
    io,
    io::{stdin, stdout, Read, Write},
    num::NonZeroUsize,
};

fn dup_input(
    input: &mut Box<dyn Read>,
    output: &mut Box<dyn Write>,
    count: NonZeroUsize,
) -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut buf = Vec::new();

    input.read_to_end(&mut buf)?;

    for _idx in 0..count.get() {
        output.write_all(&buf)?;
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let mut input: Box<dyn Read> = Box::new(stdin());
    let mut output: Box<dyn Write> = Box::new(stdout());

    dup_input(&mut input, &mut output, NonZeroUsize::new(2).unwrap())
        .expect("Failed to duplicate input");
}
```

This part works fine. I want to put a unit test on top of this and this is where the problem lies. The closest I've got to build is with the following attempt:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::{any::Any, io::Cursor};

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        let mut input: Box<dyn Read> = Box::new(Cursor::new([b't', b'e', b's', b't', b'\n']));
        let mut output: Box<dyn Write + Any> = Box::new(Vec::<u8>::new());

        assert!(dup_input(&mut input, &mut output, NonZeroUsize::new(3).unwrap()).is_ok());

        assert_eq!(output.downcast::<Vec<u8>>().unwrap().len(), 15);
    }
}
```

but rust 1.41.0 doesn't agree:

```
$ cargo test
   Compiling unbox-example v0.1.0 (/XXX/unbox-example)
error[E0225]: only auto traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object
  --> src/main.rs:39:41
   |
39 |         let mut output: Box<dyn Write + Any> = Box::new(Vec::<u8>::new());
   |                                 -----   ^^^
   |                                 |       |
   |                                 |       additional non-auto trait
   |                                 |       trait alias used in trait object type (additional use)
   |                                 first non-auto trait
   |                                 trait alias used in trait object type (first use)

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:41:39
   |
41 |         assert!(dup_input(&mut input, &mut output, NonZeroUsize::new(3).unwrap()).is_ok());
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait `std::io::Write`, found a different trait `std::io::Write`
   |
   = note: expected mutable reference `&mut std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::io::Write + 'static)>`
              found mutable reference `&mut std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::io::Write + 'static)>`

error[E0599]: no method named `downcast` found for type `std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::io::Write + 'static)>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:43:27
   |
43 |         assert_eq!(output.downcast::<Vec<u8>>().unwrap().len(), 15);
   |                           ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::io::Write + 'static)>`

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0225, E0308, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0225`.
error: could not compile `unbox-example`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Is there a way to change the unit test without changing the main code? Note: I could have used generics while implementing *dup_input* and make the problem significantly easier to solve but this code is part of a broader application and I have to use Read/Write trait objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a mutable reference to a `Box` to `dup_input` is unnecessarily complicated. You can simply pass a mutable reference to the trait object.

```
use std::{
    io,
    io::{stdin, stdout, Read, Write},
    num::NonZeroUsize,
};

fn dup_input(
    input: &mut dyn Read,
    output: &mut dyn Write,
    count: NonZeroUsize,
) -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut buf = Vec::new();

    input.read_to_end(&mut buf)?;

    for _idx in 0..count.get() {
        output.write_all(&buf)?;
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let mut input = stdin();
    let mut output = stdout();

    dup_input(&mut input, &mut output, NonZeroUsize::new(2).unwrap())
        .expect("Failed to duplicate input");
}
```

With this version, the test can be written like this:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::io::Cursor;

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        let mut input = Cursor::new([b't', b'e', b's', b't', b'\n']);
        let mut output = Vec::<u8>::new();

        assert!(dup_input(&mut input, &mut output, NonZeroUsize::new(3).unwrap()).is_ok());

        assert_eq!(output.len(), 15);
    }
}
```

We don't need to use `Any` at all here: `output` is simply a `Vec<u8>`.

Comment: I was under the impression that you always had to Box trait objects when you had to pass them as function parameters! I enjoy the simplification, thanks for the quick and helpful reply!